# Netty - eliminating info on log console

Tags: java, sockets, netty

is it possible to switch off or to prevent information output from Netty when creating `NioEventLoopGroup()`:

> "io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent `<clinit>`
>   INFORMATION: Your platform does not provide complete low-level API for accessing direct buffers reliably. Unless explicitly requested, heap buffer will always be preferred to avoid potential system unstability."

Or is there a logical workaround to prevent showing this information.

Answer (score 1):

Just switch of logging for this class in your preferred logger via configure and set it via InternalLoggerFactory.setLoggerFactory(...). By default Netty will use jdk logger

Comment: Thx so far, but may be I didn't catch it, the returned logger gives no access to configuration possibilities at all. The default logger Netty is using is Slf4j - at least in 4.0.24. But anyway - do you have some code snippets to show the correct handling? I'm not using any logger  configuration files, instead use dynamic configuration based on the JDK logger. The latter one can't be passed to .setLoggerFactory() as far I can see.